# How to make a non-id field as auto-increment in loopback4?

Tags: javascript, loopbackjs

In my application I have separate fields for Id and primary-Key (used for FK references). I want to make this Primary-Key field as auto-increment and non-id field. Is there any way to do this in loopback4? 
Pretty new to LB4.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is. Actually auto-increment is done by DB not the LB4 model. So, you just need to set auto increment for that column in DB. For example, in case of postgres DB, you should do

```
CREATE TABLE ame.auth_client (
    id                   integer  NOT NULL GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY,
    name                 varchar(100)  NOT NULL ,
    primary_key           integer  NOT NULL GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY ,
    CONSTRAINT pk_auth_client_id PRIMARY KEY ( id )
 );
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Executing update table query to set the column as auto-increment works fine. But,, how this can be manged with migrations?

Comment: I didn't get the question. You want to manage migrations from loopback framework ?  Can you confirm ?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. My question is whether it is possible by declaring the field like this
```@property({
    type: 'number',
    generated: true,
    auto-increment: true
  })
  pk: number;
```